# Variant of an Expander graph: Probability that S random points cast a shadow/projection of size at most S/2 on each face of a cube.

Tags: expander-graphs, geometric-probability, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Consider an integer cube of size $\sqrt{k} \times \sqrt{k} \times \sqrt{k}$, where $k$ is an asymptotically large perfect square number. Place k points in this cube at uniformly random locations, i.e., for each point choose its co-ordinates uniformly at random $(r_0,r_1,r_2)$ where $ 0 \leq r_i < \sqrt{k}$.

For an arbitrarily small number $\alpha >0$. Let $E$ be an event that there exists a subset of points of size $S = \alpha k$ such that the projection of these S points on every face of the cube, is of size at most $S/2$.

What is an upper bound on the probability of event $E$, i.e., P(E)?

Caution: If you start with a fixed set of size $S$, you would need to consider all possible subsets of $k$ points of size $S$. The event $E$ is defined as **there exists a subset of size $S$ in $k$ points which are randomly placed.**

Comment: You are fixing $\alpha$ and then you let $k$ go to infinity?

Comment: yes. First fix $\alpha >0$ to be a small constant and then let $k$ go to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking if you drop $k$ objects each into one of $k$ bins, what is the probability that only $k/2$ bins are occupied. (You can forget the extra dimension and only think about the dimensions you're looking at).

If you let $E_i$ be the event that the $i$th bin is empty, this has probability $((k-1)/k)^k\approx 1/e$. The events $E_i$ are approximately independent. Letting $N=\sum_{i=1}^k \mathbf 1_{E_i}$, $N$ has expectation $k/e$. The probability that there are $k/2$ unoccupied bins will decay as $e^{-\alpha k}$ using large deviation estimates.

--- Added to answer ---

If you want to pick a subset of size $\alpha k$ of the set of size $k$, it's obvious how to do it: take the boxes with the most elements first. You expect the distribution of elements in each box to be approximately Poisson with parameter 1. This means that approximately $(1-2/e)k$ of the boxes have two or more elements. As long as $\alpha$ is less than $1-2/e$, there's a high probability that you can find a subset $S$ of size $\alpha k$ whose shadow has size at most $|S|/2$.

Comment: It seems that you have computed an upper bound on the probability of a set of size $S = k$ occupying less than $S/2$ bins on one face of the cube. I am interested when there exists a subset (of size $\alpha k$) of the original set of $k$ points, such that they occupy less than or equal to $S/2$ bins on each face of the cube. Note, that there are exponential number of such subsets, i.e., $k \choose \alpha k$.

Comment: The events may be approximately pairwise independent, while not being close to $k/2$-fold independent.

Comment: I don't think they don't need to be $k$-fold independent for this kind of argument to work. 


Comment: I don't see how you are getting large deviation estimates with only pairwise independence. Consider exchangeable distributions where you choose a random size for a set, and then choose a random subset of that size. Pairwise independence is just one linear condition beyond the occupation probability. These two linear conditions don't force the distribution to be exponentially small far from the mean. For example, suppose $k=100$ and the occupation probability is $1/3$. We can achieve pairwise independence with a weighted average of sizes $33, 100$, where $100$ occurs $1/201$ of the time.  

Comment: Pairwise independence is not enough; But there is *much* more independence than that here. This kind of argument shows up all over the place in The Probabilistic Method.

Comment: Ok, I believe the conclusion, I just don't see what level of independence exists which implies it. It's also unclear to me how knowing that some subset $S$ projects to have size $|S|/2$ in one direction implies that there is some set which has small projections in all three directions. I'm only getting $\frac{2}{3}|S|$ from something like that.

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like I didn't read the question as well as I should have... I hadn't thought about the 3 different projections part of the story. To get the kind of independence you need for large deviations (at least when you're looking at projection onto one face), I think you can compare the ball dropping process with putting a Poisson number of balls (actually independently) into each bin. I see about the $2/3$ now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. May be my question is not clear.

The event $E$ is an error event for my problem and I believe (empirically verified to some extent) that $P(E) < e^{-\epsilon k}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. I want to show that there is NO set of size $S = \alpha k$ that can have projections on each face of the cube less than or equal to $S/2$. For example, if a set happens to have projections less than $S/2$ on two of the faces then it is very likely that the points will have more spread out projections on the 3rd face of the cube thus not constituting to the event $E$.


Comment: @codingTheorist: I've played with this some more. I'm sure you're right that it decays exponentially in $k$. I have tried to prove this making some assumptions that I have not justified (the applicability of large deviations techniques) together with some very crude bounds (union bounds), and have so far been unsuccessful. My idea was to pick subsets of each face of size $\alpha k$, and then to estimate the probability that for a fixed such triple, there were more than $2\alpha k$ points in the random set that project to the chosen subsets.

Comment: Although this probability does decay exponentially in $k$ (as long as the large deviation methods are valid, which I'm sure they are), the exponential decay is slower than the increase in the number of choices of subsets. This means that something more subtle is needed to finish off the argument. BTW: Even the 2D version of this problem seems non-trivial...